# Sending acknowledgment to rabbitmq server in depends on converter and listener

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

First of all, I present context of my case:
I am using `spring-boot` and `spring-rabbitmq`.  It is working for me, you should know that I must have implemented custom converter for received messages.
**(1)** From this converter can be thrown exception, for instance in case of inproper message and so on.
**(2)** After successfull converting (no exception) listener is invoked.  Then, in the listener it can also be thrown exception.

---

Now, I would like to force two things:
**(1')**  Don't requeue message in case of expcetion in converter.  Simply, send acknowledgment to queue and simulate that everything is alright.
**(2')** What is default setting in this case ? When internal `spring-rabbitmq engine` decide to send acknowledgment to queue ? When it decide command to requeue ?   Is it possible to manage it in depends on situation ?

I found in docs:

> If retries are not enabled and the listener throws an exception, by
>   default the delivery will be retried indefinitely. You can modify this
>   behavior in two ways; set the defaultRequeueRejected property to false
>   and zero re-deliveries will be attempted; or, throw an
>   AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException to signal the message should be
>   rejected. This is the mechanism used when retries are enabled and the
>   maximum delivery attempts are reached.

For example, in depends on catched exception in listener I should decide if I would like to requeue message, as I think (simply by throwing from `catch` `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException`).  I am not sure if it is good way and it is why I am asking you about your opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/).

The behavior is (mostly) controlled by the `ErrorHandler`.

Throw a `MessageConversionException` - the container requeues messages for most exceptions but some exceptions are considered fatal. Generally, if a message can't be converted, then redelivering it makes no sense.

This is all clearly explained in the section (surprisingly?) called [Exception Handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#exception-handling)

> Starting with version 1.3.2, the default ErrorHandler is now a ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler which will reject (and not requeue) messages that fail with an irrecoverable error:
>
> o.s.amqp...MessageConversionException
>
> o.s.messaging...MessageConversionException
>
> o.s.messaging...MethodArgumentNotValidException
>
> o.s.messaging...MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException
>
> The first can be thrown when converting the incoming message payload using a MessageConverter. The second may be thrown by the conversion service if additional conversion is required when mapping to a @RabbitListener method. The third may be thrown if validation (e.g. @Valid) is used in the listener and the validation fails. The fourth may be thrown if the inbound message was converted to a type that is not correct for the target method. For example, the parameter is declared as Message but Message is received.
>
> The fifth and sixth were added in version 1.6.3.

You can customize the `ErrorHandler` as needed.

Comment: And nice thing that overridiny ErroHandler I can manage of sending (n)acks. Ok, thanks. Default behaviour is reasonable. requeue means pop message and push at the end of queue ?

Comment: No; rabbitmq requeues rejected messages at the head of the queue.

Comment: So in pesimistic case we can looping. The problem is that other (correct) messages are blocked, because it is FIFO. Maybe some as `n` chances for message exists ?

Comment: There is a technique you can use - route the failed message to a DLQ, set a TTL on the DLQ and have it dead-letter expired messages back to the original queue. You can examine the x-death header to see how many times around the loop it has gone. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248441/requeueing-dead-letter-messages/31249346#31249346) for more information.

Comment: Ok, I read some about possible solution. I can see now two approaches: set `death-x` header or DLX/DLQ  approach. This second requires only `rabbitmq` configuration, no spring.  In this second solution rejected messages are written into some (lets say) box and periodically requeue to original queue. Of couerse messages rejected by `MessageConverterException` are removed, not moved to DLX. I think that messages in DLX are permanently stored.    However, what approach should I use ?  This second require spring code and give full control on livecycle of message (`n` chances), Any link about it ?

Comment: No; it doesn't work that way; all rejections will go to the DLX/DLQ if configured regardless of exception type; throw `ImmediateAcknowledgeAmqpException` to completely discard messages.

Comment: Ok, so type of exception can choose future for rejected message. However, what approach is ok for me ?

Comment: It depends on your requirements.

Comment: Ok, is there some description about `x-death` headers ?  Rejected messages (by proper exception) that are stored in DLX/DLQ are permanently in this place ?

Comment: Btw, `rabbitmq` keeps got message on the top on queue until ack ? So permanently or some timeout is defaultly set ?

Comment: You shouldn't keep asking new questions here; start a new one; the admins don't like long discussions. The message remains in an unack'd state until the consumer acks/nacks - it's not requeued on a timer - only if the consumer/channel/connection dies.

Comment: Ok, so lat quesion: unack'd state - it means that message is on the top of queue ?

Comment: No; it means it has been sent to a consumer and is waiting for ack/nack.